# ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy in spring security 3.2.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I had a working configuration with ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy and my own  sessionRegistry implementation. I upgraded to spring security 3.2.4 and had to change ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy  to ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy. and now it seems that the sessionRegistry isn't connected meaning ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthenticaton doesn't enter the sessionRegistry.registerNewSession. What to de?

my configuration xml:

```
    <security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false"
        entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">


        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />

        <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"
            ref="twoFactorAuthenticationFilter" />



        <security:logout logout-url="/player/logout"
            logout-success-url="/demo/player/logoutSuccess" />

        <security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control
                max-sessions="1" session-registry-ref="clusteredSessionRegistryImpl"
                error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
        </security:session-management>

    </security:http>



    <bean
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
        <constructor-arg ref="clusteredSessionRegistryImpl" />
        <property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/demo/player/login?login_error=true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="twoFactorAuthenticationFilter" class="com.XXX.filter.TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler" />
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="playerAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
        <property name="postOnly" value="true" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="failureHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login?login_error=true" />

    </bean>

    <bean id="bCryptPasswordEncoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider
            ref="authenticationProvider">
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

Comment: Your definition of the `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy` doesn't do or add anything, the same is configured by the namespace.

Comment: Not sure I understand. my xml puts my session registry implementation .when I call onAuthentication it doesnt enter the session registry.

Comment: The `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy` bean definition is redundant. The same is done by `<security:concurrency-control ... />` so you can remove it. Also it might break proper configuration (override things you don't want overridden). The point is that things have been split up, whereas in previous versions everything was done inside the `ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy` it is now delegated to multiple classes. However the registration of the redundant bean probably breaks the default settings and doesn't register the `RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy`.

Comment: I added a CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy that uses ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy and RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy and things work

Comment: @lior, can post your java config for this problem, i have same problem and my head got heat with this problem

Answer (score 5):

Seems I'm late with the answer, but any way..

The functionality of `ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy` is exactly split between three Strategies now - `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy`, `SessionFixationProtectionStrategy` and `RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy`.

**To have a right substitute, you should use `CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy` adding these three delegates in mentioned order.**

So, afraid, `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy` is wrongly mentioned in deprecation comment as a substitute of `ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy`. It at least requires availability of `RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy` to maintain `SessionRegistry`. Otherwise, `SessionRegistry` remains empty, and the "substitute" always reports "ok".

I guess, the approach is changed to make it more flexible having several handlers as delegates instead of one (using `CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy`, you can have any number of `SessionAuthenticationStrategy`'s doing **independent** :) things).

Comment: @Edgar, i am getting empty registry with java configuration, please help how to handle this one java config ....i am trying get all logged in users list